# How to set 1 frame per second in Camera2 android

Tags: android, frame-rate, android-camera2

I am getting Image from ImageReader but how can i slow down it 1 Frames per second without loss of app performace,

i am using this  [Code](https://gist.github.com/RoundSparrow/142b840ca86ba7a46639f23c5c0d195b) with change of image type set at JPEG as i want jpeg bytes and i have set my camera to 640x480 .

```
ImageReader.newInstance(640, 480, ImageFormat.JPEG, 2/* images buffered */);
```

So how to get 1 frame per second in below callback :

```
protected ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener onImageAvailableListener = new ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener() {
    @Override
    public void onImageAvailable(ImageReader reader) {
        Log.i(TAG, "onImageAvailable");
        Image img = reader.acquireLatestImage();
        if (img != null) {
            processImage(img);
            img.close();
        }
    }
};
```